# Не записывается объект в массив в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в переменную this.character2[i] записывается только один объект?

```
 watch: {
  id: function(){
    this.character2 = [];
    this.people = this.info.results[this.id].characters;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.people.length; i++){
      this.axios.get(this.people[i]).then(response => (this.character2[i] = response.data.name));
    }
    console.log(this.character2);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что к моменту выполнения **всех** `this.character2[i] = response.data.name`, значения `i` одинаковы и равны `this.people.length`.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.people.length; i++){
  this.axios.get(this.people[i]).then(response => (this.character2[i] = response.data.name));
}
```

---

[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)